# Loading OCX dynamically in VB 6.0

Tags: winapi, vb6, activex

I am loading OCX dynamically in VB 6.0.

The following is the code that I am using to load and call the methods:

```
Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long 
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long 
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long 
Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Any, ByVal wParam As Any, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long 

Private Sub Foo 
  On Error Resume Next 

  Dim lb As Long, pa As Long 
  Dim versionString As String 
  Dim retValue as Long 

  lb = LoadLibrary("D:\projects\other\VB_DLLs\TestDLL\TestDLL.dll")   

  'retrieve the address of getVersion' 
  pa = GetProcAddress(lb, "getVersion") 

  'Call the getVersion function' 
  retValue = CallWindowProc (pa, Me.hWnd, "I want my version", ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&) 

  'release the library' 
  FreeLibrary lb 
End Sub
```

Now I want to access public properties of OCX. How I can access (get/set) the properties of OCX?

Comment: What is your goal here?  An OCX is typically a control that is going to be displayed as a visible control on a form.  Your code indicates you are loading a DLL, without any visual presentation, and want to call that in a late-bound style.

Comment: @GTG, I actually want to set the properties of OCX, after settint the properties I want to call the method of OCX. No visual presentation on the form, just for calculation.

Comment: Have you tried normal late binding, like this:  Dim myObject as object    set myObject = createobject("yourlib.yourclass")  versionString = myObject.TheVersionProperty

Comment: You cannot use GetProcAddress with a COM dll/ocx to resolve a function name, that not how they work at all. Late binding is the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use an OCX/COM control in that manner.

To create and use an instance of the object, you will need to.. create an instance of the object, then use that.

```
Set TestObject = CreateObject("TestDll.TestObject")
Value = TestObject.Method(InputValue)
```

This requires the DLL to be registered, and will use whichever is registered rather than a specific instance.

If you don't want it to be registered, look at DirectCOM.

Comment: what is the diffrence between Controls.Add and createObject? Can I use Controls.Add instead of your approach?

Comment: `Controls.Add()` adds a control to the form (to be visible and for the user to interact with). `CreateObject()` just creates the object in memory to use programatically. I've not used `Controls.Add()` in that manner.

Comment: Actually I have tried your code its call the methods of dll perfectly, but how can I make visible object visible on form, using Controls.Add() I make control visible but with this I am not be able to call method of dll.

Comment: You should be able to call it in exactly the same way given a reference to it.

Comment: when I call the method from control object Error message shows "Object doesn't support this method or property". But its call method fine when I use CreateObject method.